# points settings table - how to design?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to come up the tables design that each category have different type of point calculation.

**First Example**: customer order a 'Intel CPU Core i7 3770K' item from CPU category - point will be calculated via (category_point / item_cost)

**Second Example**: customer order a 'OCZ SSD' item from a SSD category - point will be calculated via (`category_point` / `item_cost` + `bonus_point` + `other_name_point` + `other_name_point`)

I need to specify the fixed value for `bonus_point`, `other_name_point`, `category_point` in the table, etc It can be changed every month or so.

**Price Range Example** (Different from above) - if customer order any item from Motherboard category - point will be calculated base on item cost range like:

0.00 to £40 = 10 points

40.00 to £40 = 52 points

more than £40 = 64 points

I need to specify the point manually of the price range. This is not part of `category_point` / `item_cost` + `bonus_point` + `other_name_point` + `other_name_point`

How to design the tables for the points setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like:

**`Customers`:**

- `Id`,
- `Nam`e,
- other details
- ...

**`Orders`:**

- `Id`,
- `OrderDate`,
- `CustomerId`,
- ...

*`*ItemsOrders`:**

- `ItemId`,
- `OrderId`,
- ...

**`Items`:**

- ItemId,
- ItemName,
- CategoryId,
- `ITemCost`,
- ...

**`Categories`:**

- `CategoryId`,
- `Name`,
- ...

**`CategoryPoints`:**

- `CategoryId`,
- `PointId`,
- ...

**`Points`:**:

- `PointId`,
- `PointNam`,
- `PointCostTyp`e bit ('fixed' or 'changing'),
- ...

**`PointsCostsRanges`:** for not fixed pints only

- `Id` (Surrorgate key).
- `PointId`,
- `FromRange`.
- `ToRange`.

**Note that:**

- You didn't say how many pints' types are there for each category? Is there only three: `bonus_point`, `other_name_point` and `other_name_point`? If so you can get rid of the table `Points` and add three columns to the `CategoryPoints` table.
- In your example what 10 points actually mean? Does it mean the count of the points types that item have? for example if an itemm has three types like in your example  `bonus_point`, `other_name_point` and `other_name_point` then it has 3 points or what?
- If these ranges can change every month may be you need to add date ranges.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer Mahmoud. There will be a few fixed points and can be expanded in  the future (for example: `fulfillment_point` can be added).  In regarding 10 points example - this is base on item cost range and nothing to do with `bonus_point`, etc. First and Second examples are the same type and third example is quite different. do you understand?

Comment: I have improved my question, please check again

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back - So 10 points is a different point type?? In other words, in your example `0.00 to £40 = 10 points` what is the relation of `10 points` with other point types `bonus_point`, `other_name_point` and `other_name_point`? Is it correct to say that there is a `totalPoints` for each item = `(category_point / item_cost + bonus_point + other_name_point + other_name_point)`?

Answer (score -3):

Your examples appear to be business rules.  Business rules should be in the application code, not the data base.

However, certain values could be kept in a database table to facilitate changes.  To take your motherboard example, you could have a table structured like this:

```
Part Discount
-------------
Discount ID
Part ID
Cost
Discount
```

Values in this table would be:

```
1, 23, 4000, 10
2, 23, Max int, 64
```

Where 23 is the part number for a motherboard.

Comment: -1 for "Business rules should be in the application code, not the data base." - opinion varies but in any case that is certainly not *always* true